# How to pass variables with cakephp link?

Tags: url, cakephp, hyperlink, cakephp-2.0

I am using cakephp2.
I want to pass a variable with a hyperlink,
I use the code

```
$id=$this->Session->read('user.id');
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Edit','../posts/edit/$id');?>
```

But it didnt print the value of $id. 
It prints the url like,

```
localhost/blog/posts/edit/$id.
```

I need the url something like,

```
localhost/blog/posts/edit/33
```

How to solve it ?

Comment: -1 for complete lack of any research:  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::link

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot use variables like $id inside `''`, you need `""`.

But cleaner is:

```
->link('Edit', '../posts/edit/' . $id)
```

Even better would be to use arrays here:

```
->link('Edit', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'edit', $id)
```

Comment: I assume your first example is meant to use a dot, not a plus. You've been JS coding again, haven't you!  ;)